# I'm trying to reverse a linked list but I'm confused about how the last node works?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to reverse a singly linked list in JavaScript recursively. I already know the solution, but I need some clarification.

Here is my code:

```
var reverseList = function(head) {
    var reverse = ListNode;

    if (head == null)
        return null;

    if (head.next == null)
        return head;
    
    reverse = reverseList(head.next);
    // reverse.next = head;   //confusion here
    head.next.next = head;
    head.next = null;
    

    return reverse;
};
```

I don't understand why reverse. Next doesn't work, but head.next.next does. I thought reverse was already "pointing" to the last node, and thus we could set the next member back to head.

Would appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`reverse` is always the same node reference: it is indeed the last node from the list (in its original state). But its `next` property should only be set to the preceding node, not repeatedly to *any* node. `reverse` is the **new** head of the list in its reversed state.

Note how the value from the recursive call is taken into the `reverse` variable and at the end we return the *same* `reverse` to the previous caller. And so the main caller will get that *same* node reference back.

So it cannot be right to repeatedly set the `next` property of the *same* node.

The node that needs its `next` property changed, is the one we passed to the recursive call, as that node has become the tail in the new ordering. And that node is `head.next`, not `reverse` (which is the head in the new ordering, not the tail).